# Using vim diff to compare the working directory to the HEAD in git?

Tags: vimdiff, git

Is it possible to use `vim diff` to open and compare all the differences between `HEAD` and the files in the working directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713765/viewing-all-git-diffs-with-vimdiff

Answer (score 7):

To view unstaged modifications to your git working tree  in vimdiff, try:

```
git difftool --tool=vimdiff
```

or for staged changes

```
git difftool --tool=vimdiff [ --staged | --cached ]
```

These commands are invoking `git difftool` and specifying `vimdiff` at invocation, so should work without any prior configuration.
However, until you configure `vimdiff` as the default difftool, you will have to continue passing the `--tool=vimdiff` option to `git difftool`.
Also, I suggest incrementally increasing your usage of vim as a git diffing tool, some people suggest jumping right in re-mapping the `git diff` command to use vimdiff, but retaining the ability to use `git diff` can still be useful.
Also some people suggest turning off prompting, i.e. running

```
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

I don't use this because I want to go back to a shell between viewing files, so I can cancel out of the diff'ing if necessary.

#### making edits right there in vimdiff

An advantage of using vim over `git diff` is that when you are viewing unstaged or staged files in `vimdiff` you can go ahead and change the file right there in vim, which is really handy.
You need to use `:w!` to force past vims warning of modifying a read only file though. Also, if you change a file that was staged, you will need to re-stage to include the edit into the next commit.

#### Setting vimdiff as your git difftool

You can use

```
git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
```

or put

```
[diff]
    tool = vimdiff
```

into your `~/.gitconfig` or to be repo specific: `.git/config`